# Threading in websites

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website running on IIS which has a timer that checks for files to be processed after every 5 minutes. If files found then it runs a separate task thread for each file to be processed. Just wanted to know if this is the best approach to get maximum performance.

Comment: Long-running tasks isn't a good choice for IIS, because web server manages the lifetime of your site. It can shutdown your application due to inactivity, when there are no incoming requests, and run new instance when needed. There are some solutions, like Hangfire (see http://hangfire.io/), which can workaround this behavior. Also, you may consider windows service to do periodic job, and and use site as a facade to the results.

Comment: Yep, I'll second the Hangfire recommendation. Thats basically why it exists. Provides a lovely management UI too to save you writing all that guff :)

Comment: Another for Hangfire, Works great.